# Using basic authentication with SyncFusion ej.DataManager

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

I'm struggling to setup SyncFusions ej.Grid to use basic authentication when getting or updating data with my API. Has anyone had experience with this? Their [examples](https://help.syncfusion.com/js/grid/data-binding#remote-data) seem sparse.

I've got some examples below of what I've tried. Given the following setup code:

```
var ticket = "Basic " + Base64.encode("username:password");

$('#Grid').ejGrid({
    dataSource: dataManager,
    allowPaging: true,
    columns: ["AccountName", "CompanyName"]
});
```

This code brings up chrome basic auth prompt:

```
var dataManager = ej.DataManager({
    url: "/api/app/imports/3",
    adaptor: new ej.WebApiAdaptor()
});
```

This code brings up chrome basic auth prompt.

Attempted because there is a "headers" object used in data.min.js

```
var dataManager = ej.DataManager({
    url: "/api/app/imports/3",
    adaptor: new ej.WebApiAdaptor(),
    headers: {
        Authorization: ticket
    }
});
```

This code errors: Uncaught TypeError: this.adaptor.processQuery is not a function

Attempted due to https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/117024/does-datamanager-support-odata-v4

```
var dataManager = ej.DataManager({
    url: "/api/app/imports/3",
    adaptor: new ej.WebApiAdaptor().extend({
        beforeSend: function() {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", ticket);
        }
    })
});
```

This code brings up chrome basic auth prompt:

```
var dataManager = ej.DataManager({
    url: "/api/app/imports/3",
    adaptor: new ej.WebApiAdaptor(),
    beforeSend: function() {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", ticket);
    }
});
```

This code brings up chrome basic auth prompt:

```
var dataManager = ej.DataManager({
    url: "/api/app/imports/3",
    adaptor: new ej.WebApiAdaptor()
});

dataManager.dataSource.beforeSend = function() {
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", ticket);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much debugging of minified code I have found that the `ej.DataManager` constructor does accept a `headers` property, but requires a list of objects and uses each of the properties of each of those objects as HTTP headers. So the following code will include the header you are looking for:

```
var dataManager = ej.DataManager({
    url: "/api/app/imports/3",
    adaptor: new ej.WebApiAdaptor(),
    headers: [{
        Authorization: ticket
    }]
});
```